# Signification of Identity provider Binding

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am implementing SSO using an external Identity provider to which I do not have access yet.

The IDP metadata IDPSSODescriptor has one SingleSignOnService tag with a binding value of: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST

Does this imply that I cannot initiate an authentication request to the SingleSignOnService location with a GET request or that the service will respond with a POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the protocol endpoints that you will interact with expect POST interaction from the client (typically a browser). This is required these days for sending the assertion from the IdP to SP, but Redirect is usually acceptable in the case of the SP sending an AuthnRequest to the IdP.